# Getting byte array through input type = file

Tags: javascript, html, fileapi

```js
var profileImage = fileInputInByteArray;

$.ajax({
  url: 'abc.com/',
  type: 'POST',
  dataType: 'json',
  data: {
     // Other data
     ProfileImage: profileimage
     // Other data
  },
  success: {
  }
})

// Code in WebAPI
[HttpPost]
public HttpResponseMessage UpdateProfile([FromUri]UpdateProfileModel response) {
  //...
  return response;
}

public class UpdateProfileModel {
  // ...
  public byte[] ProfileImage {get ;set; }
  // ...
}
```

```html
<input type="file" id="inputFile" />
```

I am using ajax call to post byte[] value of a input type = file input to web api which receives in byte[] format. However, I am experiencing difficulty of getting byte array. I am expecting that we can get the byte array through File API.

Note: I need to store the byte array in a variable first before passing through ajax call

Comment: you need to share your code... server side and client side

Comment: @ArunPJohny i have updated the code. note that i am not allow to use server side solution to get byte array of input file before posting

Comment: Please visit this link : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31433413/return-the-array-of-bytes-from-filereader

Comment: Related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47574218/converting-from-blob-to-binary-to-save-it-to-mongodb/49660839#49660839

Comment: To Arun's point, there's literally nothing here for getting the input bytes.  No attempt made.  The code above is the sending/receiving code, only, which is largely irrelevant to this question.  To me, that deserves a downvote on the question.  It's an important question, deserving of an answer, but it requires a lengthy answer just to get a person up to speed.  It's like asking "How do I pilot a plane" instead of "What are the parameters I need to know in order to know if I can take off?"

Comment: Also related - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37134433/convert-input-file-to-byte-array/49676679#49676679

Answer (score 68, accepted):

### **[Edit]**

As noted in comments above, while still on some UA implementations, `readAsBinaryString` method didn't made its way to the specs and should not be used in production.
Instead, use `readAsArrayBuffer` and loop through it's `buffer` to get back the binary string :

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function() {

  var reader = new FileReader();
  reader.onload = function() {

    var arrayBuffer = this.result,
      array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer),
      binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array);

    console.log(binaryString);

  }
  reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);

}, false);
```

```html
<input type="file" />
<div id="result"></div>
```

For a more robust way to convert your arrayBuffer in binary string, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16365505/3702797).

---

### [old answer] <sub>(modified)</sub>

Yes, the file API does provide a way to convert your File, in the `<input type="file"/>` to a binary string, thanks to the [FileReader](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader) Object and its method [`readAsBinaryString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString).
[**But don't use it in production !**]

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function(){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
        var binaryString = this.result;
        document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = binaryString;
        }
    reader.readAsBinaryString(this.files[0]);
  }, false);
```

```html
<input type="file"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

If you want an array buffer, then you can use the [`readAsArrayBuffer()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer) method :

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function(){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
        var arrayBuffer = this.result;
      console.log(arrayBuffer);
        document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = arrayBuffer + '  '+arrayBuffer.byteLength;
        }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
  }, false);
```

```html
<input type="file"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Comment: how do i assign the readAsArrayBuffer result and pass through ajax call?

Comment: in the reader load event, call your ajax function with the arraybuffer as argument ( `reader.onload = function(){ yourAwesomeAjaxFunction(this.result)};` and then `function yourAwesomeAjaxFunction( profileImage ){ $.ajax({
  url: 'abc.com/',...`

Comment: it seems that the request accepted by web api is null. however, i got the length display. How can i output the display of arraybuffer in alert form ?

Comment: `arrayBuffer.byteLength`it's in the code snippet I gave you

Comment: i mean the this .result return null in web api, and when i alert it, it shows [object ArrayBuffer]

Comment: Then you may not need an array buffer? Can't say without seeing your server side code, but you may want to use a [`FormData`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/FormData) to send the file directly ?

Comment: i need an byte array. how can i convert from array buffer or base64 to byte array?

Comment: arrayBuffer is a byte array, however you can convert it to typed array using `new Int32Array(buffer);` or any other typed array constructor

Comment: this has no support for ie and is deprecated. i would suggest switching to the mentioned method: readAsArrayBuffer

Comment: @BenSewards, you're right readAsBinary unfortunately got deprecated. I'll update the answer to focus on readAsArrayBuffer when I'll get a keyboard under hand. Thanks for the head's up.

Comment: hi Kaiido, I get an error which says `maximum call stack size exceeded` for even images > 100kb.. is it possible to do anything about it?

Comment: @Rai yes, this is because in javascript, functions have a maximum number of arguments they can receive. By using `String.fromCharCode.apply` we convert every elements of our array to an argument, and when the  array has to many elements, we reach the *maximum call stack*. The easy way to workaround this is to loop over every elements (`binaryString = ""; for(let i=0; i<array.length; i++) binaryString += String.fromCharCode(array[i]);`. And for an even more robust solution, you can check [the link](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16365505/3702797) in the answer

Comment: It's throwing "Maximum call stack size exceeded" error

Comment: @AamirNakhwa yes, it may do so with too big data, as I said in the answer, "For a more robust way to convert your arrayBuffer in binary string, you can refer to [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16365505/3702797)"

Answer (score 12):

Modern browsers now have the [`arrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer) method on `Blob`'s:

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', async (event) => {
  const buffer = await event.target.files[0].arrayBuffer()
  console.log(buffer)
}, false)
```

Answer (score 11):

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
    (function (document) {
  var input = document.getElementById("files"),
  output = document.getElementById("result"),
  fileData; // We need fileData to be visible to getBuffer.

  // Eventhandler for file input. 
  function openfile(evt) {
    var files = input.files;
    // Pass the file to the blob, not the input[0].
    fileData = new Blob([files[0]]);
    // Pass getBuffer to promise.
    var promise = new Promise(getBuffer);
    // Wait for promise to be resolved, or log error.
    promise.then(function(data) {
      // Here you can pass the bytes to another function.
      output.innerHTML = data.toString();
      console.log(data);
    }).catch(function(err) {
      console.log('Error: ',err);
    });
  }

  /* 
    Create a function which will be passed to the promise
    and resolve it when FileReader has finished loading the file.
  */
  function getBuffer(resolve) {
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileData);
    reader.onload = function() {
      var arrayBuffer = reader.result
      var bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
      resolve(bytes);
    }
  }

  // Eventlistener for file input.
  input.addEventListener('change', openfile, false);
}(document));
});
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>

<input type="file" id="files"/>
<div id="result"></div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Note that versions of IE before 11, I believe, don't support the use of `Promise` objects.

Comment: hi sebu.. Thanks for this answer.. this seems to work for me.. but, which of `arrayBuffer` and `bytes` is the byte array? If `bytes` is(as per the name), then what is `arrayBuffer`? @vapcguy, would be really grateful if you could help me out too here..

Comment: @Rai `arrayBuffer` would probably be the one you want, but when I was looking at this, I couldn't figure it out, either, and went my own way with `reader.readAsDataURL(f);` (instead of `reader.readAsArrayBuffer(fileData);` ) where I used `var f = files[0];`, which is similar to `fileData` above except I didn't cast it to a `Blob` first. I provided an answer on this question, too, and it was written for React originally, but a careful reading of it will give you a vanilla JS version, too.

Answer (score 6):

This is a long post, but I was tired of all these examples that weren't working for me because they used Promise objects or an errant `this` that has a different meaning when you are using Reactjs.  My implementation was using a DropZone with reactjs, and I got the bytes using a framework similar to what is posted at this following site, when nothing else above would work:  https://www.mokuji.me/article/drop-upload-tutorial-1 .  There were 2 keys, for me:

1. You have to get the bytes from the event object, using and during a FileReader's onload function.
2. I tried various combinations, but in the end, what worked was:

   `const bytes = e.target.result.split('base64,')[1];`

Where `e` is the event.  React requires `const`, you could use `var` in plain Javascript.  But that gave me the base64 encoded byte string.

So I'm just going to include the applicable lines for integrating this as if you were using React, because that's how I was building it, but try to also generalize this, and add comments where necessary, to make it applicable to a vanilla Javascript implementation - caveated that I did not use it like that in such a construct to test it.

These would be your bindings at the top, in your constructor, in a React framework (not relevant to a vanilla Javascript implementation):

```
this.uploadFile = this.uploadFile.bind(this);
this.processFile = this.processFile.bind(this);
this.errorHandler = this.errorHandler.bind(this);
this.progressHandler = this.progressHandler.bind(this);
```

And you'd have `onDrop={this.uploadFile}` in your DropZone element.  If you were doing this without React, this is the equivalent of adding the onclick event handler you want to run when you click the "Upload File" button.

```
<button onclick="uploadFile(event);" value="Upload File" />
```

Then the function (applicable lines... I'll leave out my resetting my upload progress indicator, etc.):

```
uploadFile(event){
    // This is for React, only
    this.setState({
      files: event,
    });
    console.log('File count: ' + this.state.files.length);

    // You might check that the "event" has a file & assign it like this 
    // in vanilla Javascript:
    // var files = event.target.files;
    // if (!files && files.length > 0)
    //     files = (event.dataTransfer ? event.dataTransfer.files : 
    //            event.originalEvent.dataTransfer.files);

    // You cannot use "files" as a variable in React, however:
    const in_files = this.state.files;

    // iterate, if files length > 0
    if (in_files.length > 0) {
      for (let i = 0; i < in_files.length; i++) {
      // use this, instead, for vanilla JS:
      // for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
        const a = i + 1;
        console.log('in loop, pass: ' + a);
        const f = in_files[i];  // or just files[i] in vanilla JS

        const reader = new FileReader();
        reader.onerror = this.errorHandler;
        reader.onprogress = this.progressHandler;
        reader.onload = this.processFile(f);
        reader.readAsDataURL(f);
      }      
   }
}
```

There was this question on that syntax, for vanilla JS, on how to get that file object:

[JavaScript/HTML5/jQuery Drag-And-Drop Upload - "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'files' of undefined"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10813494/javascript-html5-jquery-drag-and-drop-upload-uncaught-typeerror-cannot-read)

Note that React's DropZone will already put the File object into `this.state.files` for you, as long as you add `files: [],` to your `this.state = { .... }` in your constructor.  I added syntax from an answer on that post on how to get your File object.  It should work, or there are other posts there that can help.  But all that Q/A told me was how to get the `File` object, not the blob data, itself.  And even if I did `fileData = new Blob([files[0]]);` like in sebu's answer, which didn't include `var` with it for some reason, it didn't tell me how to read that blob's contents, and how to do it without a Promise object.  So that's where the FileReader came in, though I actually tried and found I couldn't use their `readAsArrayBuffer` to any avail.

You will have to have the other functions that go along with this construct - one to handle `onerror`, one for `onprogress` (both shown farther below), and then the main one, `onload`, that actually does the work once a method on `reader` is invoked in that last line.  Basically you are passing your `event.dataTransfer.files[0]` straight into that `onload` function, from what I can tell.

So the `onload` method calls my `processFile()` function (applicable lines, only):

```
processFile(theFile) {
  return function(e) {
    const bytes = e.target.result.split('base64,')[1];
  }
}
```

And `bytes` should have the base64 bytes.

**Additional functions:**

```
errorHandler(e){
    switch (e.target.error.code) {
      case e.target.error.NOT_FOUND_ERR:
        alert('File not found.');
        break;
      case e.target.error.NOT_READABLE_ERR:
        alert('File is not readable.');
        break;
      case e.target.error.ABORT_ERR:
        break;    // no operation
      default:
        alert('An error occurred reading this file.');
        break;
    }
  }

progressHandler(e) {
    if (e.lengthComputable){
      const loaded = Math.round((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
      let zeros = '';

      // Percent loaded in string
      if (loaded >= 0 && loaded < 10) {
        zeros = '00';
      }
      else if (loaded < 100) {
        zeros = '0';
      }

      // Display progress in 3-digits and increase bar length
      document.getElementById("progress").textContent = zeros + loaded.toString();
      document.getElementById("progressBar").style.width = loaded + '%';
    }
  }
```

And applicable progress indicator markup:

```
<table id="tblProgress">
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td><b><span id="progress">000</span>%</b> <span className="progressBar"><span id="progressBar" /></span></td>
    </tr>                    
  </tbody>
</table>
```

And CSS:

```
.progressBar {
  background-color: rgba(255, 255, 255, .1);
  width: 100%;
  height: 26px;
}
#progressBar {
  background-color: rgba(87, 184, 208, .5);
  content: '';
  width: 0;
  height: 26px;
}
```

**EPILOGUE:**

Inside `processFile()`, for some reason, I couldn't add `bytes` to a variable I carved out in `this.state`.  So, instead, I set it directly to the variable, `attachments`, that was in my JSON object, `RequestForm` - the same object as my `this.state` was using.  `attachments` is an array so I could push multiple files. It went like this:

```
  const fileArray = [];
  // Collect any existing attachments
  if (RequestForm.state.attachments.length > 0) {
    for (let i=0; i < RequestForm.state.attachments.length; i++) {
      fileArray.push(RequestForm.state.attachments[i]);
    }
  }
  // Add the new one to this.state
  fileArray.push(bytes);
  // Update the state
  RequestForm.setState({
    attachments: fileArray,
  });
```

Then, because `this.state` already contained `RequestForm`:

```
this.stores = [
  RequestForm,    
]
```

I could reference it as `this.state.attachments` from there on out.  React feature that isn't applicable in vanilla JS.  You could build a similar construct in plain JavaScript with a global variable, and push, accordingly, however, much easier:

```
var fileArray = new Array();  // place at the top, before any functions

// Within your processFile():
var newFileArray = [];
if (fileArray.length > 0) {
  for (var i=0; i < fileArray.length; i++) {
    newFileArray.push(fileArray[i]);
  }
}
// Add the new one
newFileArray.push(bytes);
// Now update the global variable
fileArray = newFileArray;
```

Then you always just reference `fileArray`, enumerate it for any file byte strings, e.g. `var myBytes = fileArray[0];` for the first file.

Answer (score 4):

This is simple way to convert files to Base64 and avoid "maximum call stack size exceeded at FileReader.reader.onload" with the file has big size.

```js
document.querySelector('#fileInput').addEventListener('change',   function () {

    var reader = new FileReader();
    var selectedFile = this.files[0];

    reader.onload = function () {
        var comma = this.result.indexOf(',');
        var base64 = this.result.substr(comma + 1);
        console.log(base64);
    }
    reader.readAsDataURL(selectedFile);
}, false);
```

```html
<input id="fileInput" type="file" />
```

Answer (score 2):

```js
document.querySelector('input').addEventListener('change', function(){
    var reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
        var arrayBuffer = this.result,
array = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer),
  binaryString = String.fromCharCode.apply(null, array);

console.log(binaryString);
      console.log(arrayBuffer);
        document.querySelector('#result').innerHTML = arrayBuffer + '  '+arrayBuffer.byteLength;
        }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.files[0]);
  }, false);
```

```html
<input type="file"/>
<div id="result"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is one answer to get the actual final byte array , just using `FileReader` and `ArrayBuffer` :

```
 const test_function = async () => {

      ... ... ...

      const get_file_array = (file) => {
          return new Promise((acc, err) => {
              const reader = new FileReader();
              reader.onload = (event) => { acc(event.target.result) };
              reader.onerror = (err)  => { err(err) };
              reader.readAsArrayBuffer(file);
          });
       }
       const temp = await get_file_array(files[0])
       console.log('here we finally ve the file as a ArrayBuffer : ',temp);
       const fileb = new Uint8Array(fileb)

       ... ... ...

  }
```

where `file` is directly the `File` object u want to read , this has to be done in a `async` function...