# Angular 2 - upload of file

Tags: post, file-upload, angular, asmx

I need to create upload of images to my webserver in my Angular 2 app. Can anybody provide me some guidance how to achive this?

**These are the prerequisities:**

- ASMX web service communicating in JSON.
- post method used for communication.
- JPEG / PNG up to 1MB of size.

**Concept I wanted to follow (but failed)**

Load the content of JPEG to variable, encode it using the Base64 coding and post it to ASMX service that will accept two parameters (token for authentication and encoded data.

**What exactly is my problem**

Web service was the easy part, it is done and working, but I can't manage to get the file content for enconding. I used this:

component.html

```
...
<input type="file" (change)="fileChangeEvent($event)" />
...
```

component.ts

```
private fileChangeEvent(fileInput: any) {
    let image = fileInput.target.files[0] as File;
    ...
}
```

As you have probably guessed, the problem is in the File class, because it provides me only basic info about the file (name, size, last modif, ...) but I can't get the content of the file. Or at least I don't know how to get it. I also checked other questions here on SO, but all of the answers had something special that did not met my requirements. And maybe I'm just blind, but I can't see where the content is get.

So, is there anybody, who is able to provide me some guidelines to follow?

Thank you very much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have left this question open for experienced guys, who could be able to answer it. There is no answer though and I found out the answer yesterday. So, after some research and modification of search phrase, I found out the answer. There is a FileReader type which can be used for reading the content of the file. Here is the source of the answer:

[Getting byte array through input type = file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556664/getting-byte-array-through-input-type-file)

Thanks to original answer now I know how to do it.