# Convert upload file to byte array to be sent to API request in Angular/Typescript

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

How can I convert a uploaded file to byte array in *Angular/Typescript*?

Component.ts

```
 buildRequest(): CreateRequest { 
 var reader = new FileReader();  
    return {
      create: {
        fileData: this.reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.fileToUpload)        
      }
    };
  }
```

Model

```
export interface CreateRequest {
    create: {
      fileData: Uint8Array[]; // Also, is this correct representation of byte array?
    };
  }
```

Currently, I am getting an error when I am assigning `ReadAsArrayBuffer` function to fileData -

> "Type 'void' is not assignable to type 'Uint8Array[]'"

.

What is the correct way of sending byte array to API request?

Comment: Not in a position to check, but it seems readAsArrayBuffer might not return anything, or it might be a promise or something. I would first inspect the return signature of readAsArrayBuffer..

Answer (score -2):

The question has been answered [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45267800/convert-file-to-byte-array-angular-2)!

I believe the attribute is string, blob or any.

```
export interface CreateRequest {
    create: {
      fileData: string|any;
    };
}
```

***Btw, IO functions are asynchronous (probably in any language)!***, you need use event listeners.

```
reader.addEventListener('loadstart', handleEvent);
reader.addEventListener('load', handleEvent);
reader.addEventListener('loadend', handleEvent);
reader.addEventListener('progress', handleEvent);
reader.addEventListener('error', handleEvent);
reader.addEventListener('abort', handleEvent);
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/load_event

If you need another references, hope your helps!

https://nehalist.io/uploading-files-in-angular2/

Comment: Can you change my code and try to get it working. I tried this but this isn't working

Comment: Friend!
Method **readAsArrayBuffer** is Javascript.
You tried this?

Comment: This returns void. How do I send it over to the API?

Comment: IO functions are asynchronous (probably in any language)!

Another example... 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/load_event