# javascript - Different SHA256 using the same file in Angularjs app and bash

Tags: javascript, angularjs, sha256, cryptojs, ng-file-upload

I need to get the digest of an uploaded file in my AngularJS app, but the result digest is different from the file digest I get with bash.

I started using [jshashes](https://github.com/h2non/jshashes), but when I saw that the resultant hash (on the web app) was different from the one which I get locally using bash I decided to move to [CryptoJS](https://github.com/brix/crypto-js). But the result is the same,the hash from the uploaded file is still different.

Here's my code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();    
reader.readAsBinaryString(controller.file);
controller.fileHash = CryptoJS.SHA256(reader.result).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
```

As you can see the code is quite simple, just reads the uploaded file from the variable using `FileReader` and convert the value into a BinaryString, hash the content and finally assign the result to another controller valriable to show it in the html.

In my shell (local environment) to get the file digest I run the following command:

```
$ shasum -a 256 [path/to/file]
```

In order to upload files, i'm using [ng-file-upload](https://github.com/danialfarid/ng-file-upload)

What I'm missing? If anyone can help me or guide me to see the solution I will be very greatful.

Thank you in advance.

**Update 1**:
As @destroyer said in the comments below `readAsBinaryString` is deprecated and it's an asynchronous method, so here's my actual code:

```
var reader = new FileReader();
reader.onload = function() {
    controller.fileHash = CryptoJS.SHA256(reader.result).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(controller.file);
```

I tried [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32556944/2132144) solution in order to convert the `ArrayBuffer` object into a `BinaryString`. But the result is still wrong.

**Update 2**: 
Here's an image of a console log og the object I want to hash
[image: File object console.log]

Comment: Can we see the "local" code?

Comment: @destoryer I've just edited the question. To sum up, in my local environment I run this command: `$ shasum -a 256 [path/to/file]`

Comment: I deleted my answer as I can't seem to help you: I've used [js-sha256](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha256) on `ArrayBuffer`s in the past without any problems.

Comment: @destroyer you did it... thank you very much. It works. I've spend a couple of days trying to solve it, I don't know why I didn't find this library until now, but it works! If you write an answer with just a link to the library, I will vote it.

Comment: Glad to help, the answer is back and updated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`readAsBinaryString`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsBinaryString) is deprecated, you should use [`readAsArrayBuffer`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FileReader/readAsArrayBuffer).

Either way, those functions start an asynchronous operation, the result of which you read inside the `FileReader` instance's `load` event.

```
var reader = new FileReader();    
reader.onload = function(){
  controller.fileHash = CryptoJS.SHA256(reader.result).toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex);
};
reader.readAsArrayBuffer(controller.file);
```

Reflecting on our conversation in comments: the problem was that `crypto-js` does not operate on binary files, but on strings.

You can get a SHA256 implementation that supports `ArrayBuffer`s directly in [`js-sha256`](https://github.com/emn178/js-sha256).

Comment: @destroyer you are right. My mistake. Sorry. Even though the result is still wrong. I tryed to convert  the result into a binary string, following the instructions in this (https://stackoverflow.com/a/32556944/2132144) response, but the result is still wrong. I don't know what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: Are you sure `controller.file` is a `File`or `Blob`?

Comment: @destroyer Yes, i'm pretty sure that it's a File. I'm going to update the original question with an image of a `console.log` of the object. Please, check it.

Comment: One more thing that crosses my mind - try removing `.toString(CryptoJS.enc.Hex)`

Comment: @destroyer the output is an WordArray Object. Teh documentation say that you need to convert into a string callint `.toString` method and passing an encoder.