# Accessing byte array from <audio> in web audio api

Tags: javascript, typescript, web

I'm creating a component to view an audio file, that part I've already achieved, which can be seen in this [image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b2xwD.png).

My biggest problem now is that I need a way to get all the bytes of the audio file, using the Web Audio API or some other method in typescript (preferably) or javascript.

I have researched and found the AnalyserNode, however it shows only a part of the audio being executed, it does not provide an array with all the bytes of the file.

Does anyone know of any other solution?

Thank you.

Comment: Thanks, I thought I was in the portuguese section. I translated it.

Comment: What about just reading the file's bytes? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556664/getting-byte-array-through-input-type-file/32556944 are you sure you need to read the bytes?...

Comment: Are you sure you want the *bytes in the audio file* and not the *raw PCM samples from the audio*?

Comment: PCM samples could works too.