# How to push upload file data to json object in Angular 7

Tags: angular, file-upload, angular7

Hay, my angular project have user register form, in that i want to upload user image and enter data push to web api. In that case i will push user entered data to json object. So i want to push upload file data and as well as other data to object body.

In separate function i will call to upload file, that's work fine.(i will do it for testing purpose, but i want to push as one object with all data)

Angular 7 cli

#### registed-page.component.ts

```
onSubmit(form:NgForm){ 
    var customerData = { 
       "cusName": form.value.userName,
       "cusPassword": form.value.password,
       "cusEmail": form.value.email, 
       "cusImage" : ############
    }; 

    //OTHER CODE TO PUSH THAT JSON OBJECT TO WEB API-------
}




 //for image upload ----------------------------------------
  public uploadFile (getData){
    if (getData.length === 0) {
      return;
    }

    let fileToUpload = <File>getData[0];
    const ImageData = new FormData();
    ImageData.append('file', fileToUpload, fileToUpload.name);

    this.http.post('https://localhost:44301/api/Customer/CustomerFileUpload', ImageData)
      .subscribe(event => {
        console.log("imae upload ----> "+event) 
      });
  }
  //for image upload ----------------------------------------
```

#### register-page-component.html

```
<form (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(formData)" #formData="ngForm" > 

  <input  #file type="file"  name="file" >

  <input 
  (click)="uploadFile(file.files)"   
  class="btn btn-large btn-lg btn-circle"   
  type="submit">

</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can convert the file to `byte array`/`binary string`/`base64` and pass it with the json.

There are many ways to convert the file. Please find the post below

[Convert file to byte Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556664/getting-byte-array-through-input-type-file/32556944)

One of them is to convert it to base64:

```
fileToUpload.toDataURL("image/jpeg")
```

To pass data in `formData` format:

> **UI:**

```
  let formData: FormData = new FormData();
  formData.append("cusImage", fileToUpload);
  formData.append('cusName', form.value.userName);
  formData.append("cusPassword", form.value.password);
  formData.append('cusEmail', form.value.email);

  this.http.post(apiUrl, formData)
  .subscribe(event => {
    console.log(event) 
  });
```

> **Backend**:

**Controller**

```
    [HttpPost]
    [Route("upload")]
    public async Task<IActionResult> Upload([FromForm]FileUploadDTO model)
    {
       //Code to save data
         ...
    }
```

**Model**

```
public class FileUploadDTO
{
    public IFormFile cusImage { get; set; }
    public string cusName { get; set; }
    public string cusPassword { get; set; }
    public string cusEmail { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I haven't no idea regarding `byte array`. can you help me in that case.

Comment: without converting `byte array/binary string/base64` is that possible to upload as image to server, from json object.

Comment: Well., what I did was instead of passing json, I passed formdata to the backend. Along with file, I appended other propertiesof the json too with the formdata. If you want I can share the code

Comment: I am in transition. Will share once I reach home

Comment: yeah sure, i'll hope. Thank you.

Comment: I have added the code. If your backend is in dotnet, I can share backend code

Comment: My backend was dotnet core. your's one is dotnet?

Comment: Wow..  Mine is dotnet core too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/193337/discussion-between-thevin-malaka-and-adrita-sharma).