# Convert an uploaded image file into byte array and post it to the back end

Tags: arrays, image, typescript, angular6

Upload an image file, convert the image file into a byte array and send it to back end through post method

I tried to use the FileReader() and covert it to a array buffer. But it gave me an undifined object.

This is my button I used to upload the image. And when the form is submit I am calling onSubmit function to post the data.

```
<input type="file" style="display: none" accept="image/*" (change)="onFileChanged($event)" #fileInput>
    <a mat-raised-button class="btn" (click)="fileInput.click()">Upload Logo</a>
    <img class="btn" *ngIf="selectedFile != null" style="width: 30%; height: 3%" src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{selectedFile}}">
    <img *ngIf="selectedFile == null"  style="display: none">
```

Here is the function I used to upload the image

```
onFileChanged(event) {
    this.selectedFile = event.target.files[0];
    console.log('Selected file before:',this.selectedFile);
    let reader = new FileReader();
    reader.onload = function(){
      let arrayBuffer = this.result;
      let bytes = new Uint8Array(arrayBuffer);
      console.log(bytes);
    }
    reader.readAsArrayBuffer(this.selectedFile);

  }
```

Here is my onSubmit function

```
onSubmit() {

      const data = {};
      data['name'] = this.addEntityForm.value.entityCode;
      data['description'] = this.addEntityForm.value.entity;
      data['displayName'] = this.addEntityForm.value.eDisplayName;
      if (this.selectedFile != null){
        data['logo'] = this.selectedFile;
        console.log('Inside the selectedFile if');
        console.log(this.selectedFile);
      }
      else {
        data['logo'] = null;
        console.log('Inside the else')
      }
      data['status'] = 'ACTIVE';


      console.log('Posted data :', data);

      this.profileServise.addNewEntity(data).subscribe( result => {

        if (result) {
          this.globalService.updateEntityTable(result);
        }
        this.openSnackbar('New Entity Created Successfully');
        this.matDialogRef.close();
      }, error => {
        this.openSnackbar('An Error in Creating a New Entity');
      });

  }
```

I want to send the uploaded image as a byte array to the back end

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Getting byte array through input type = file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556664/getting-byte-array-through-input-type-file)

Comment: @PrashantPimpale I tried the things in that question.But still I am struggling to convert it to byte stream and post.

Comment: it that API is working from PostMan?

Comment: Shouldn't `event.target.result` be `this.result`?

Comment: My mistake.It should be this.result thanks @dezfowler

Comment: Did that fix the problem? If not what error are you getting and on what line? Also, is the file valid? Are you able to upload it to an existing website e.g. Google Drive or something like that?

Comment: It didn't solved my problem. I solved this issue by sending image and the required data as form data and in the back end I converted image into byte array using getBytes() method.  ```@ResponseStatus(HttpStatus.OK)
    @RequestMapping(value = "/addNewEntity", method = RequestMethod.POST)
    public ResponseEntity<CompanyDTO> photoUploaded(@RequestParam(value = "logo", required = true) MultipartFile logo){byte[] image = new byte[0];

        try {
             image = logo.getBytes();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }