# How get a buffer object from input type=file in html5 like fs readFile in nodejs

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, input, file-upload

//html5

```js
let file = document.getElementById('input').files[0];
console.log(file);
```

//nodejs

```js
const md5 = require('md5')
const fs = require('fs')
fs.readFile('xxx.mp4', (err, data) => {
  console.log(data);
});
```

i want get the same value between md(file) and md(data).
how escape the object file to buffer?
How get a buffer object from input type=file in html5 like fs readFile in nodejs

#### thanks!!!

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32556664/getting-byte-array-through-input-type-file/32556944

Comment: Short version is read an array buffer and use its contents: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Blob/arrayBuffer